# Is the app "E-mail Client App - myMail" a part of ios 14?

Tags: iphone, ios, applications, email

I just upgraded my iPhone to ios 14.7 and I noticed something weird.  When I checked my Screen Time usage, I see an app that I don't recognize nor remember installing.  It's called "E-mail Client App - myMail".  Apparently it's running all the time out of all my programs b/c it has the highest usage.

I noticed it is in the AppStore and it shows I haven't installed it because the blue "Get" button appears and not the cloud icon with the down arrow to signify I've downloaded it before.

So my question is why is it appearing in my Screen Time app when I haven't installed it at any time on my iPhone?  Did I somehow have malware installed on my phone?  Did I somehow get tricked into installing a similar program that's spoofing to be the legit one?

EDIT: I took a closer look and it's listed under "Games" and the developer is MGL My.COM (CYPRUS) Limited.  I'm looking at my games and there's no game that I can see that's created by this developer.  I found a link on wikipedia for this company (My.COM) but I don't have any game from the list in the wikipedia article.

Comment: It's on the app store - https://apps.apple.com/us/app/e-mail-client-app-mymail/id722120997 Looks like an actual mail client, not a game

Answer (score 1):

I actually had this same issue. An app I was using claimed it was an app called email to go.
After searching on the Apple forums I found that their main advice was to reset the phone.
This made no sense to me as a solution so I developed  my own in order to investigate the root cause.
I set a usage timer for the ‘email to go app’ with a time limit of one minute.
I have about 100 games, so you can imagine it took a while to figure out what app it was.
Eventually, a game called Merge Master started flagging me asking if I wanted to ignore my time limit, and it became clear the app guilty of being email to go was in fact merge master. I have contacted their staff to make them aware of this issue.
Past that I have not found a way to resolve the issue, only to identify the root cause.

Answer (score 0):

Type E-mail Client App - myMail appearing in screen time into google. You'll see plenty of similar posts from users on both Reddit and the Apple Support Forums. When did this start, and what have you installed recently? For the few that have gotten answers, it always seems to be, as you said in your post, a game made by the same company. Don't use the wikipedia article. Just go directly to the companies site and take a look at whether you have any of their games installed.